# Problem Using ROW_NUMBER() function in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, window-functions

I would like to have a row number column in a select table output, but when I try using the ROW_NUMBER() function MariaDB throws a syntax error. There are several references on the web (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/ ) but so far I have not been successful.  Here is a segment of my MariaDB table:

```
+---------------------+------------+  
| date_reading        | temp_patio |
|---------------------+------------+  
| 2019-09-03 06:26:00 |       17.6 |  
| 2019-09-03 06:33:00 |       17.5 |  
| 2019-09-03 06:40:00 |       17.5 |  
| 2019-09-03 06:46:00 |       17.5 |  
| 2019-09-03 06:53:00 |       17.4 |  
| 2019-09-03 07:00:00 |       17.4 |  
| 2019-09-03 07:07:00 |       17.4 |  
| 2019-09-03 07:13:00 |       17.4 |
```

The document says that the options for the "***OVER ()"*** option are optional, but I have tried both with and without an OVER () clause and with and without an ***ORDER BY*** clause.

Here is my select command:

> select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ) as Therow, * from MyData where
>   Date_Reading > Now()- INTERVAL 3 HOUR;

Optionally I have tried without the `OVER ()` clause and also using `OVER ( ORDER BY ID)`.

My MariaDB version is

> Server version: 10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Raspbian 9.0

Can someone assist?...RDK

Comment: According to the official MariaDB documentation for `ROW_NUMBER`, it is [only supported on 10.2 versions and later](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/).  So, your version may not even support `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: what is your maria db version

Comment: OK, looks like I need to update.  This is surprising as I only installed it on this Raspberry Pi via the normal "sudo apt-get install mariadb-server" about a week ago. Their libraries may be lagging? What is the correct process to get 10.2 onto this Pi? And, are there issues using a "new" version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Window functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/) are supported in MariaDB 10.2 or higher version only.

MariaDB 10.2 or higher:

```
SELECT 
    MyData.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) as Therow
FROM MyData 
WHERE Date_Reading > Now()- INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
```

For lower version:

We can use the [MySQL variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to do this job.

```
SELECT 
    MyData.*, 
    @row_num:= @row_num + 1 AS Therow
FROM 
    MyData, 
    (SELECT @row_num:= 0 AS num) AS c
WHERE Date_Reading > Now()- INTERVAL 3 HOUR
ORDER BY test.`date` ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks, until I can get the upgraded version, that works like a charm

Comment: Note this trick with `@row_num` might not work if you order by two columns.

Comment: How do I make this create the column in my table so its in my database table and not an output?

Comment: Pick PK & row_number for this output and join the same table again with PK(primarykey) and use update statement