# mysql query result to get one record on same id

Tags: mysql

Hi looking to see how would i write the mysql statement that result in one record if there have same id.

I have two tables order_userinfos and orders, here my join statement

```
SELECT *
  FROM col_order_userinfos i
  JOIN col_orders o
    ON i.col_order_id = o.order_number
 WHERE o.order_number > 226690
```

The results came out like this

```
col_order_userinfo_id   virtuemart_order_id virtuemart_user_id  address_type
   51548                 226691                2611                BT
   51549                 226691                2611                ST
   51550                 226692                2611                BT
   51551                 226692                2611                ST
   51552                 226693                2611                BT
   51553                 226693                2611                ST
   51554                 226694                2611                BT
```

As you can see, I get same order_id result twice with the address_type either 'ST' OR 'BT'
also, I have one order_id that have one order_id and address_type 'BT'.

Here the result i am looking for

```
col_order_userinfo_id   virtuemart_order_id virtuemart_user_id  address_type
     51549               226691                2611                ST
     51551               226692                2611                ST
     51553               226693                2611                ST
     51554               226694                2611                BT
```

I tried with group by order_id in my query, the results will only show up with address_type 'BT'. 
What would be the best way to write mysql statement that get my desire result?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) function like

```
SELECT col_order_userinfo_id,
      virtuemart_order_id,
      virtuemart_user_id,
      address_type
FROM (
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.col_order_userinfo_id 
                         ORDER BY i.col_order_userinfo_id DESC) AS row_num
  FROM col_order_userinfos i
  JOIN col_orders o
    ON i.col_order_id = o.order_number
 WHERE o.order_number > 226690 ) xx
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: It seems the OP wants the greater col_order_userinfo_id per virtuemart_order_id so `ORDER BY i.col_order_userinfo_id DESC` should be added to the subquery

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and advice, currently I have MariaDB 10.0.38 on my host so, i don't think i can use the row_number() function. is there other method around?

Comment: For earlier versions of MariaDB you will need to simulate the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. See here: [MySQL tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) and here: [Stack Overflow Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765698/problem-using-row-number-function-in-mariadb)

Comment: Since i haven't update the MariaDB version on my box, I have this mysql statement so and came out as desire result on my case. Trying to using the Order BY  in a From Subquery method. Here the statement

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `col_order_userinfos` a
               WHERE a.`col_order_id` > 226690               
ORDER BY a.`col_order_userinfo_id` DESC
               LIMIT 18446744073709551615
               ) AS Hello
GROUP BY Hello.col_order_id INNER JOIN col_orders table